# Ektron 9 Database only installation

Tags: sql, exe, ektron

is there any way to install ektron9 database independently in my pc.
Reson: when installing ektron9 for some reason database is not installed,installing that site take more time,so i have to do the same process repenting to try database installation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to install a full Ektron site in IIS in order to create an Ektron database.  When the installation is complete, it will automatically run the CMS400 Site Setup utility for you.  This gives you the following options:

- CMS400 Full Installation
- CMS400 Upgrade
- CMS400 Database Setup

You can select Database Setup to create the database.  If Ektron is already installed, you can re-run this utility via the start menu (`All Programs > Ektron > CMS400v90 > Utilities > CMS400 Site Setup`) or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ektron\CMS400v90\Utilities\SiteSetup\cms400sitesetup.exe`.

*Now, I don't claim to be the official voice of Ektron, so use this next comment at your own risk (or perhaps with Ektron Support on the line ;) )*

Inside that SiteSetup folder is a subdirectory called `Database`, and it has lots of sql scripts in it.  It may be possible that you could manually execute some or all of those, probably in a particular order, and end up with an Ektron database.  If you try that, it's worth noting that there's another sql script here:  `C:\Program Files (x86)\Ektron\CMS400v90\startersites\CMS400Min\Setup\database\cms400_data.sql`.

The short version of this answer:  install Ektron somewhere if you want to do it the "right" way.  :)